# Sehch touch call controller on list item tap

Tags: sencha-touch

Here is my Sencha view:

```
Ext.application({
 name: 'Sencha',
 launch: function() {
     var panel = new Ext.Panel({
    fullscreen: true,
    dockedItems: [
      {
        xtype: "label",
        dock: "top",
        html: "<div style='backbround'>KK TEST",
        style: "width:100%;text-align:center;font-weight:bold"

      },
      {
        xtype: "toolbar",
        items: [
          {
            iconMask: true,
            iconCls: "download"
          },
          {
            iconMask: true,
            iconCls: "favorites"
          },
          {
            iconMask: true,
            iconCls: "search"
          },
          {
            iconMask: true,
            iconCls: "user"
          }
        ]  
      },
      {
        xtype: 'list',
        itemTpl: '{title}',
        store: {
            fields: ['title', 'url'],
            data: [
                {title: 'Locate a centre', url: 'ext-scheduler-2-0-upgrading-to-ext-js-4'},
                {title: '<a href="/centres" style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;">Browse all kwikkopy centres</a>', url: 'sencha-touch-2-what-to-expect'},
                {title: 'Sencha Con 2011', url: 'senchacon-2011-now-packed-with-more-goodness'},
                {title: 'Documentation in Ext JS 4', url: 'new-ext-js-4-documentation-center'}
            ]
        },
        itemConfig: {
          tpl: '{url}'
        },
        listeners: {
          select: function(itemConfig) {
            console.log(store)
            alert('tapped on '+ itemConfig   )
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  });    }
});
```

I want to call a controller and redirect to the next page when I click on a list item.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your listeners config in this:

```
listeners:{
    itemtap:function(data,index){
        var record = data.getStore().getAt(index);
         // the record that has been clicked.
         Ext.dispatch({
            controller: 'ControllerName'
            ,action: 'ControllerMethod'
            ,record: record
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and edits for the questions.   
I changed the code as you said, now it errors out saying `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'dispatch'` at line calling `Ext.dispatch`

Comment: Are you using sencha touch 2? If so that's why Ext has no method 'dispatch' and since I'm not yet familiar with ST2 I can't help you. If you are not using sencha touch then check if you included the sencha touch js file and check if there is another exception thrown before the itemtap function get called. But you probably are using ST2 anyway.. :)